# capture whole of line

Tags: regex, preg-match

How to capture whole of a line, which has 'mystring'.
example:

```
mystring    er  as
        mystring2            //spaces before and after string
```

I've tried `^` and `$`, but doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to include or exclude the line with mystring2 in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match a string with any variation of 'mystring' this will do: `/^.*mystring.*$/m`

If you strictly want to match 'mystring' you will need [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): `/^.*\bmystring\b.*$/m`

Pattern Explained:

- `^` begin match the start of the data or a newline character
- `.*` match zero or more characters that are not a newline
- `\b` match a word boundary
- `mystring` match the string: mystring
- `\b` match a word boundary
- `.*` match zero or more characters that are not a newline
- `$` match the end of the data or a newline character (EOL)

The 'm' flag makes ^ and $ match newlines within data.

Example script:

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
        mystring0            
mystring    er  as
        mystring2            //spaces before and after string
EOT;

// match mystring and mystring2 for example
preg_match('/^.*mystring.*$/m', $string, $match);
echo "MATCH: <pre>" . $match[0] . "</pre>\n"; // prints '        mystring0            '

// only match mystring and mot mystring2 for example
preg_match('/^.*\bmystring\b.*$/m', $string, $match);
echo "MATCH: <pre>" . $match[0] . "</pre>\n"; // prints 'mystring    er  as'
?>
```

*b.t.w. The pre tags are the so spaces will not be trimmed in HTML output, just from the comment about the space I thought maybe that was your problem.*

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*mystring.*$
```

You might need capturing parentheses, but probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the flag `m` for a multilines catch, and watches that both masks `.*` are ungreedy.
In PHP:

```
#^(.*?mystring.*?)$#m
```

or

```
#^(.*mystring.*)$#Um
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$string = '
mystring    er  as
        mystring2            //spaces before and after string
';
preg_match_all('/(.*\bmystring\b.*)+/m', $string, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     mystring    er  as
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     mystring    er  as
        )

)
```